# How to make sure animations are executed in queue

Tags: jquery, animation

I have to animate divs. I need to make sure that as a button is clicked the *old* divs fade out completely before letting the *new* divs fade in.

```
showNews: function() {
    var start = this.counter * this.displayatonce;
    var end = this.counter * this.displayatonce + (this.displayatonce - 1);

    for (i=start; i<=end; i++) {
        this.news.eq(i).fadeIn();
    }

},

hideAllNews: function() {
    this.news.fadeOut();
},

navigateNews: function() {
    this.hideAllNews();
    this.showNews();
},
```

how do I make this work?

Comment: Shouldn't this work as-is, as jQuery queues subsequent animations by default?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's animation functions take a callback function as a parameter. Start animations that you want to execute after another animation in its callback.

Example:

```
elememtsToHide.fadeOut(function() {
  elementsToShow.fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Yes but I don't know why if I use this method, my divs fadeOut, then fadeIn... and fadeOut again! And the fadeOut method is only called once.

Comment: Then you must be doing something else. Can you put a working example online e.g. with jsfiddle.net

Comment: But you are not using the callback in that example.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what callback?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your latest comment eariler: All jQuery effect methods such as `fadeOut` have a callback parameter as I used in my example. Read about it in documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/